# Allocated storage has been exhausted - scale storage to resolve

Tags: amazon-rds

I get the above message in my Amazon RDS instance alerts section. How do I get notified by email when such violations are reported by RDS.

Answer (score 2):

The most straight forward option for monitoring [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) (and any other AWS service for that matter) is [Amazon CloudWatch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/), which *provides a reliable, scalable, and flexible monitoring solution that you can start using within minutes* and specifically includes [Alarms](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudwatch_concepts.html#CloudWatchAlarms):

> [...] Alarms can automatically initiate actions on your behalf, based
>   on parameters you specify. An alarm watches a single metric over a
>   time period you specify, and performs one or more actions based on the
>   value of the metric relative to a given threshold over a number of
>   time periods. **The action is a notification sent to an Amazon SNS topic**
>   or Auto Scaling policy. [...] *[emphasis mine]*

[Amazon SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) *supports notifications over multiple transport protocols* in turn, amongst those Email and Email-JSON, see the respective FAQ [What are the different delivery formats/transports for receiving notifications?](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#13):

> [...] Customers can select one the following transports as part
>   of the subscription requests:
>
> - [...]
> - ”Email”, “Email-JSON” – Messages are
>     sent to registered addresses as email. Email-JSON sends notifications
>     as a JSON object, while Email sends text-based email.

The metric in question is the *FreeStorageSpace* RDS metric (see [Amazon RDS Dimensions and Metrics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/CW_Support_For_AWS.html#rds-metricscollected) for details on the available ones) as discussed in [Scaling DB Instance Storage](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ScalingStorage.html):

> **Important**
>   We highly recommend that you constantly monitor the
>   FreeStorageSpace RDS metric published in CloudWatch to ensure that
>   your DB Instance has enough free storage space. For more information
>   on monitoring RDS DB Instances, see [Viewing DB Instance Metrics](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.html).

Accordingly, you'll need to create an alarm mirroring or approximating the threshold reported to you by AWS in the console, publish it to an SNS topic and subscribe to this topic via an email address of your choice.